# Special Characters in MySQL bash statement causing fail

Tags: bash, special-characters

I am attempting to automate the creation of MySQL users -- So I am building a `bash` cron that will create them on the fly.  The problem is, that when I create them, I am using a random password generation which can include characters such as `^` `$` `%` etc etc ..

Using the following fails:

```
create_database=$(mysql --login-path=local -se "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234!!ABC^@DEFGH';")
```

Whereas the following succeeds:

```
create_database=$(mysql --login-path=local -se "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';")
```

Is it the CLI or `bash` script that doesn't like the password, or is it MySQL that doesn't like it?  Is there a work-around?  I'd like to do this in bash vs a scripting language like PHP/PERL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shell issue. In the example you show, the characters `!!` are being processed by shell history expansion before they are sent to the mysql client. So you are setting the password:

```
1234cd srcABC^@DEFGH
```

Assuming `cd src` was the command you ran before this one. `!!` is replaced with the previous command in your shell history.

There are lots of special characters in the shell that cause various expansion effects inside double-quoted strings.

You can read `man bash`:

> There are seven kinds of expansion performed: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion.
>
> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done  in  a  left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and pathname expansion.
>
> On systems that can support it, there is an additional expansion available: process substitution.

To master shell programming, you basically need to study all of these and understand which ones work inside different types of quotes.

Comment: Well that makes a whole lot of sense now ..  I think the best method here is to read about that, and exclude what I can from my password generator.  Thank you for your generous answer ..  It was very helpful.